# Find the max value of the same length nails after hammered

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Given an array of positive integers, and an integer *Y*, you are allowed to replace at most *Y* array-elements with lesser values. Your goal is for the array to end up with as large a subset of identical values as possible. Return the size of this largest subset.
>
> The array is originally sorted in increasing order, but you do *not* need to preserve that property.
>
> So, for example, if the array is [10,20,20,30,30,30,40,40,40] and *Y* = 3, the result should be 6, because you can get six 30s by replacing the three 40s with 30s. If the array is [20,20,20,40,50,50,50,50] and *Y* = 2, the result should be 5, because you can get five 20s by replacing two of the 50s with 20s.

Below is my solution with O(nlogn) time complexity. (is that right?) I wonder if I can further optimize this solution?

Thanks in advance.

```java
public class Nails {

    public static int Solutions(int[] A, int Y) {
        int N = A.length;
        TreeMap < Integer, Integer > nailMap = new TreeMap < Integer, Integer > (Collections.reverseOrder());
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (!nailMap.containsKey(A[i])) {
                nailMap.put(A[i], 1);
            } else {
                nailMap.put(A[i], nailMap.get(A[i]) + 1);
            }
        }
        List < Integer > nums = nailMap.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

        if (nums.size() == 1) {
            return nums.get(0);
        }

        //else
        int max = nums.get(0);
        int longer = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < nums.size(); j++) {
            int count = 0;
            if (Y < longer) {
                count = Y + nums.get(j);
            } else {
                count = longer + nums.get(j);
            }
            if (max < count) {
                max = count;
            }
            longer += nums.get(j);
        }
        return max;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String[] input = scanner.nextLine().replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "").split(",");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input));
            int[] A = new int[input.length - 1];
            int Y = Integer.parseInt(input[input.length - 1]);
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                if (i < input.length - 1) {
                    A[i] = Integer.parseInt(input[i]);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            int result = Solutions(A, Y);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't have O(n) time complexity.

Comment: @AndyTurner Sure? To me it does have a linear time complexity.

Comment: @Olivier `treeMap.put` is not `O(1)` even in theory

Comment: @AndyTurner : could you please tell me your thoughts?

Comment: For {1,1,4} and Y=2, it should return 2, right? Your code gives 3.

Comment: @SomeDude You're right, I missed that.

Comment: @Olivier no, it should return 3, as now you can hammer A[2] down to length 1 and finally get 3 nails in length 3.

Comment: You mean, when you hammer a nail, you can choose the amount? You can hammer a nail so that its length is reduced by 2?

Comment: Yes, given Y=2, you are allowed to hammer 0/1/2 nails with any length.

Comment: What is the expected output for y=3 and `{1,2,2,3,3,3,3,5,5}` ? Is it 5 ? ( there are two possible solutions `{1,2,2,2,2,2,3,5,5}`  and  `{1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,5}` ).

Comment: @c0der It's 6: {1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3}

Comment: @Olivier to go from 5,5 to 3,3 you need y=4

Comment: @c0der , actually Olivier is right, Y is not the length you can hammer, it is the number of nail.

Comment: Are the lengths ordered (ascending) to begin with? If not: are the lengths integral and is the range known?

Comment: @greybeard Thanks so much for reminding! The array is always given in ascending order and the range is with int limit I think. I don't remember the exact values. Updated in the description.

Comment: (Thanks for the update. A known smallish set of possible values would have enabled establishing the multiplicities in linear time as does ordered input (and ordering them: "counting sort).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the array is sorted to begin with, a reasonably straightforward *O*(*n*) solution is, for each distinct value, to count how many elements have that value (by iteration) and how many elements have a greater value (by subtraction).

```
public static int doIt(final int[] array, final int y) {
    int best = 0;
    int start = 0;
    while (start < array.length) {
        int end = start;
        while (end < array.length && array[end] == array[start]) {
            ++end;
        }

        // array[start .. (end-1)] is now the subarray consisting of a
        // single value repeated (end-start) times.
        best = Math.max(best, end - start + Math.min(y, array.length - end));

        start = end; // skip to the next distinct value
    }
    assert best >= Math.min(y + 1, array.length); // sanity-check
    return best;
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks

Comment: (You can even try and establish the run lengths in less than O(*n*) time using [exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search) - doesn't help the worst case of *n* runs.)

Answer (score 7):

A C++ implementation would like the following where A is the sorted pin size array and K is the number of times the pins can be hammered.
{1,1,3,3,4,4,4,5,5}, K=2    should give 5 as the answer 
{1,1,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6}, K=2    should give 6 as the answer

```
int maxCount(vector<int>& A, int K) {
    int n = A.size();
    int best = 0;
    int count = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n-K-1; i++) {
        if (A[i] == A[i + 1])
            count = count + 1;
        else
            count = 1;
        if (count > best)
            best = count;
    }
    int result = max(best+K, min(K+1, n));
    
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, iterate through all the nails and create a hash `H` that stores the number of nails for each size. For [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4], `H` should be:

```
size     count
 1    :    1
 2    :    2
 3    :    3
 4    :    3
```

Now create an little algorithm to evaluate the maximum sum for each size `S`, given `Y`:

```
BestForSize(S, Y){
    total = H[S]
    while(Y > 0){
        S++
        if(Y >= H[S] and S < biggestNailSize){
            total += H[S]
            Y -= H[S]
        }
        else{
            total += Y
            Y = 0
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Your answer should be `max(BestForSize(0, Y), BestForSize(1, Y), ..., BestForSize(maxSizeOfNail, Y))`.

The complexity is O(n²). A tip to optimize is to start from the end. For example, after you have the maximum value of nails in the size 4, how can you use your answer to find the maximum number of size 3?

Comment: Thanks Daniel! But I think you may misunderstand my example. Y simply means the number of nails you can hammer down,

Comment: Oh, sorry. Let me see if I understood, suppose you have a nail of size 1 and a nail of size 3. With Y = 1, would I be able to hammer the nail of size 3 how many times I want (e.g.: until it has size 1) ? Or it means that I can only hammer it once, so it gets size 2?

Comment: The former is right, you can hammer the nail of size 3 to size 1 with Y=1.

Comment: Fixed the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my java implementation: First I build a reversed map of each integer and its occurence for example {1,1,1,1,3,3,4,4,5,5} would give {5=2, 4=2, 3=2, 1=4}, then for each integer I calculate the max occurence that we can get of it regarding the K and the occurences of the highest integers in the array.

```
public static int ourFunction(final int[] A, final int K) {         
    int length = A.length;
    int a = 0;
    int result = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int previousValue = 0;

    TreeMap < Integer, Integer > ourMap = new TreeMap < Integer, Integer > (Collections.reverseOrder());
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (!ourMap.containsKey(A[i])) {
            ourMap.put(A[i], 1);
        } else {
            ourMap.put(A[i], ourMap.get(A[i]) + 1);
        }
    }
    
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : ourMap.entrySet()) {
        if( a == 0) {
            a++;
            result = entry.getValue();
            previousValue = entry.getValue();
        } else {
            if( K < previousValue) 
                b = K;
            else 
                b = previousValue;
            if ( b + entry.getValue() > result )
                result = b + entry.getValue();
            previousValue += entry.getValue();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful to also explain your answer rather than just giving code as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Since the array is sorted, we can have an O(n) solution by iterating and checking if current element is equals to previous element and keeping track of the max length.

```
static int findMax(int []a,int y) {
    int n = a.length,current = 1,max = 0,diff = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i< n; i++) {
        if(a[i] == a[i-1]) {
            current++;
            diff = Math.min(y, n-i-1);
            max = Math.max(max, current+diff);
        }else {
            current = 1;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

given int array is not sorted than you should sort

```
public static int findMax(int []A,int K) {
    int current = 1,max = 0,diff = 0;
    List<Integer> sorted=Arrays.stream(A).sorted().boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    for(int i = 1; i< sorted.size(); i++) {
        if(sorted.get(i).equals(sorted.get(i-1))) {
            current++;
            diff = Math.min(K, sorted.size()-i-1);
            max = Math.max(max, current+diff);
        }else {
            current = 1;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<Integer> A = Arrays.asList(3,1,5,3,4,4,3,3,5,5,5,1);
    int[] Al = A.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();

    int result=findMax(Al, 5);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```